# .htaccess file gives 500 Internal Server Error when I added 'directory' option

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, internal-server-error

htaccess file content;

```
#RewriteEngine On
#ErrorDocument 404 ./404.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

I am trying to accesable sub-folder (and pages under subfolder), and I added a .htaccess file into my subfolder and its content like that;

```
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
```

Also in httpd.conf file I have;

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysub/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Now currently when I try to access folders, they have basic auth. and it is okay, but when I try to access 'mysub' folder, it gives 500 Internal server error. why it is happenning ? Thank you

Comment: Go check the server’s error log.

Comment: @CBroe it says ' <Directory not allowed here '

Comment: If you read [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory), that should be no surprise – it clearly states, “Context: server config, virtual host”. The easiest solution would be to put only what’s inside the `Directory` directive in your code now into a .htaccess that gets placed in the sub-folder.

Comment: @CBroe this time folders ok but subfolder gives 500 and log says ' allow not allowed here '

Comment: `Allow` has context `directory, .htaccess`, so it is allowed inside .htaccess. Please update your question to show _exactly_ what you have put where now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it;

create a new .htaccess file in that subdirectory that contains this:

```
Satisfy any
```

To do this in the main Apache configuration using :

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysubfolder>
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Thanks..